# Strange version string / number error when using pillow

Tags: python, versioning, dependency-management, pyautogui

This simple python program:

```
import pyautogui

# Get the screen size
screen_size = pyautogui.size()

# Capture the screen and save it to a file
screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
screenshot.save("screenshot.png")
```

Breaks with a very strange error from pyscreeze:

```
% python3 screenshot.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ken/Programs/Neil/screenshot.py", line 7, in <module>
    screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyscreeze/__init__.py", line 527, in _screenshot_osx
    if tuple(PIL__version__) < (6, 2, 1):
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

What I have tried:

1. pip3 install --upgrade pillow
   which took it to pillow-10.0.0.
2. update pyscreeze to the latest
   This gives the strange error below but an update to pyautogui then goes without a hitch.  None of which resolves the original str / int problem.

Please tell me how to address this kind of error.

```
% pip3 install pyscreeze
Collecting pyscreeze
  Using cached PyScreeze-0.1.29-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyscreenshot (from pyscreeze)
  Using cached pyscreenshot-3.1-py3-none-any.whl (28 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow>=9.2.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from pyscreeze) (9.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: EasyProcess in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from pyscreenshot->pyscreeze) (1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: entrypoint2 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from pyscreenshot->pyscreeze) (1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: mss in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from pyscreenshot->pyscreeze) (9.0.1)
Installing collected packages: pyscreenshot, pyscreeze
**ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.**
pyautogui 0.9.54 requires pygetwindow>=0.0.5, which is not installed.
Successfully installed pyscreenshot-3.1 pyscreeze-0.1.29
```

Comment: the error might suggest your `pip` utility may be out-of-date and need updating, possibly try: `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` and re-run the script, possibly reinstalling some or all of the dependent packages, eg. `pyautogui`

Answer (score 1):

My assumption from seeing your code is that you might be having problems with versions. Because when I ran it in my python virtual environment it worked just fine.
I think the following answer will work for you...

[Create a python virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) and then just install pyautogui with `pip install pyautogui` or create a requirement.txt in your project directory and paste the below stuff into it,

```
EasyProcess==1.1
entrypoint2==1.1
MouseInfo==0.1.3
mss==9.0.1
Pillow==10.0.0
PyAutoGUI==0.9.54
PyGetWindow==0.0.9
PyMsgBox==1.0.9
pyperclip==1.8.2
PyRect==0.2.0
pyscreenshot==3.1
PyScreeze==0.1.29
pytweening==1.0.7
```

then run the command `pip install -r requirements.txt`.
With these requirements within a virtual environment...

It should work without any problem!

Answer (score 0):

What version of pygetwindow do you currently have installed?

What is the result if you try:

```
pip3 install pygetwindow==0.0.5
```

Seems like your current pygetwindow version might conflict with the version pyautogui requires. I would suggest trying virtual environment like [Anaconda](https://docs.anaconda.com/free/anaconda/install/index.html) so your library versions for this project dont conflict with versions from other projects.

Comment: Thanks, Mike, but nothing changed.  Former pygetwindow version was 0.0.9